# Share Point 2007 Dll Error

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, solution, multi-project

I m Trying To Deploy a Solution With 3 Project (Multi Project Solution ) on our sharepoint Server .

dll of One Of This Solution In Which  I have Put My Enums , Struct  and Common Stuff 
get into trouble after deploy .

when  i deploy the new solution it will be  deployed  successfuly but 
it seems that the deploy proccess dont replace older dll with the new ones 
and after this when i want to test the site the page that i have used that mentioned  enums in it   do not work correctly

(the value of one of the radio button in page is coming from the enums that i have mentioned  )

it will give me java script error  and none of the event of my page fire

Any Help Will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the new dll's are not deployed? Are you deploying to GAC? If yes can you check whether it's just that changes are not picked? And also please ensure you are recycling the app pool else the system might be picking the cached copy of your dll.

Comment: what is the reason for recycling the app pool

Comment: The assemblies gets cached while execution and hence it needs recycle. Sample path of where the caching happens - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Temporary ASP.NET Files. The path would var depending on your .net version and the OS being 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Dear nitin i have recycled the app pool and reset the iis after that i build my solution again and copy the mentioned dll manually into the GAC but again not working i do not know what should i  do  :(

Comment: can you do it the other way round. Although I doubt if it will help but worth giving it a shot - deploy the latest to GAC first and then fire IISReset or App Pool recycle.

Comment: Dear @Nitin I Have Restart Our SharePint Server And Now Its Working  Tanx Dude

Comment: No worries, glad it worked. But yeah you would want to do an app pool recycle every time you deploy a new change to GAC.